# NodeJs with ExpressJs API gets 404 when I publish it to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, web-deployment

This is driving me crazy. I've created an app with NodeJs, ExpressJs and Angular. I've got a client folder, which is Angular driven and a Server folder, where I have my ExpressJs REST Api.

On my local system it uses the IP address and port and looks like this:
0.1.2.3:3000/getusers. This works fine on my system.

When I push it to the host I get a 404 error when calling the API. The client is fine. In the dev console I can see the same URL format: 2.2.2.3:3000/getusers.

What am I missing here?

This is the app.js config I'm using:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var getusers = require('./routes/getusers');
var test = require('./routes/test');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

/**
 * Development Settings
 */
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    // This will change in production since we'll be using the dist folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
    // This covers serving up the index page
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app')));

    // Error Handling
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Production Settings
 */
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {

    // changes it to use the optimized version for production
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });
}


/**
 * Routes
 */
app.use('/getusers', getusers);
app.use('/test', test);



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Your error handler middleware should come at last before any other routes are registered. Move the `Routes` to upper. I guess you will get a 404 error even in development if you specify `NODE_ENV=development` environment.

Comment: I could see from your routes that on /getusers, the **signup** is called. But signup is not declared as a variable. It should have been 
`app.use('/getusers', getusers);`

How could this run in local though?

Comment: Hi Shriram, That was a  typo. I added that for the example, but it's actually correct in the code.

Comment: Zeronone, I'm not sure what you mean. Where should I place the Routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeronone was right on his post. This fixed it.

Your error handler middleware should come at last before any other routes are registered. Move the Routes to upper. I guess you will get a 404 error even in development if you specify NODE_ENV=development environment. – zeronone Jun 25 at 7:39